Simultaneous volume control for devices on Pipewire
I'm on Debian Bookworm with KDE plasma. To replace pulseaudio with pipewire, I cleared the directories with pulseaudio settings: ~/.config/pulse, /etc/pulse and /usr/share/pulse and installed the wireplumber, pipewire-pulse and pipewire-audio packages.
After this, volume control occurs separately for speakers and headphones. For example, with my headphones off, I change the speaker volume to 50%. I'd like to see this change apply to headphones as well. Also, and vice versa, changing the volume when headphones are connected should be applied to the speakers when they are disconnected. It seems that volume levels are now saved separately for speakers and headphones. What pipewire configuration changes do I need to make to adjust volume levels simultaneously for headphones and speakers?

you should have not done that cleaning of /etc/ and /usr/share. These are apt-managed directories.

As far as I know, pipewire uses its own configuration files. Since my system does not currently have the pulseaudio package, I decided that these directories with configuration files would no longer be needed. I removed them after pulseaudio was replaced by pipewire.

I can't tell you what you removed, but when debian removes a package, it removes its data files at well – and debian doesn't allow anything but data files in /usr/share, so if the files were still there, it's almost certain they belonged to a package that was still installed. /usr/share does not contain configuration.
